# Geometric interpretation of Prime Avoidance Lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm doing [Gathmann's commutative algebra notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/commalg-2013/commalg-2013.pdf) Exercise 2.10:

> Let $R$ be a ring.
> (a) Let $I_1,..., I_n\unlhd R$ and $P\unlhd R$ be a prime ideal. If $P\supset I_1\cap\cdots\cap I_n$, prove that $P\supset I_k$ for some $k=1,...,n$.
> (b) Let $I\unlhd R$, let $P_1,...,P_n\unlhd R$ be prime ideals. If $I⊂ P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_n$, prove that $I⊂ P_k$ for some $k=1,...,n$.
> (c) Show that the statement of (b) still holds if $P_1$ is not necessarily prime (but $P_2,...,P_n$ still are).
> Can you give a geometric interpretation of these statements?

I proved the two statements, but I'm not sure about the geometric interpretations.

For (a), since intersection of ideals correspond to union of subvarieties, prime ideals correspond to irreducible subvarieties, it can be interpreted as, if an irreducible subvariety is contained in the union of some subvarieties, then it is contained in one of them. This one is easy to imagaine geometrically, since an irreducible subvariety is, by definition, not a union of subvarieties.

For (b), $P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_n$ generates $P_1+\cdots+P_n$, and the sum corresponds to the intersection of some subvarieties, so the statement can be interpreted as, if a subvariety contains the intersection of some irreducible subvarieties, then it contains one of these subvarieties. I'm not sure about this one because I can's see why it is geometrically true. Suppose we have two circles in $\mathbb A_\mathbb R^2$ which intersect at two points $(a_1,a_2)$ and $(b_1,b_2)$, then $V(x-a_1,y-a_2,x-b_1,y-b_2)$ is a subvariety contains the two points but not contains any of the circle, so I think my interpretation is wrong.

I have seen the comment in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321410/geometric-statement-of-prime-avoidance) which seems to be right, but can someone explain more? In particular, why is my translation of the prime avoidance lemma wrong? I'm only learning commutative algebra, so I'm not familiar with algebraic geometry.

Comment: "if a subvariety contains the intersection of some irreducible subvarieties, then it contains one of these subvarieties" - this is definitely not true. For 2 lines that meet at a point, another variety can contain the point but not the lines

Comment: To get a geometric interpretation, try taking the contrapositive, and use elements to get a statement about hypersurfaces